# C# GIS Bing Maps

Tags: c#, bing-maps

I'm developing an application in C# and I want to show my data on map like Bing maps, so what is the best the best way to do that.

I have seen SharpMap but I could not load Bing map to it.

please direct me to a start point as I'm new in GIS.

Comment: why the qgis tag? please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a WPF or WinForm app you can use the Bing Maps WPF control. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750210.aspx